# Security Group Ingress rule automatically wiped out

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks

I have deployed AWS EKS 3 node cluster(Version 1.13). It contains some ELBs, microservices and a  UI hosted on Kubernetes. ELB's have their own security group. I modify security group's ingress rules manually to enable access to UI for specific IP's on port 8080. However, I have noticed that after couple of days an ingress rule automatically gets added for port 8080 get removed and all are publically accessible (0.0.0.0/0).

It seems this behaviour happens when a node from EKS cluster goes down. However I have not seen such thing but still, ingress opens for all public access. 
Not sure what exactly is missing. The cloud trail entry shows IAM id which belongs to the EKS role but not sure why such occurrences happen.

Comment: Can inspect CloudTrial to look for api calls if someone, or some service, did remove them.

Comment: @Marcin The cloud trail entry shows IAM id which belongs to the EKS role but not sure why such occurrences happen.

Comment: some ingress controller (e.g. nginx) allows you to control the ingress rule based on IP address and port number. Hence, any events which causes re-deployment of ingress controll might revert your changes.

Comment: @sayboras We do not have any nginx but we have a security group where in we add whitelist IP's for ingress on port 8080 for our tomcat jar. Do you think this could be an issue?

Comment: I am not sure, but one component must be doing it. Are you using AWS ALB ingress ?

Comment: @sayboras I am using Classic ELBs.

Comment: could be related to this https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-aws/issues/65